# MATLAB R2015a won't start on 14.04

Tags: 14.04, virtualbox, opengl, matlab

I recently downloaded MATLAB R2015a on my ubuntu 14.04 virtualbox. When I try to run it, I get the blue matlab logo screen and the following error in terminal:

libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so

libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast

MATLAB is selecting SOFTWARE OPENGL rendering

When I try to run it as a superuser, I get a licensing error. I'm pretty new to ubuntu and linux in general--let me know if you can help.

Comment: Do you have a video card capable of running open-gl? (there are many ways to check this... [here is an example](http://superuser.com/questions/244630/how-do-i-tell-if-my-graphics-card-supports-opengl-2-0)). If so, run `matlab -nosoftwareopengl` in a terminal to run Matlab in a hardware mode. Let's see what results.

Comment: I have Innotek systemberatung gmbh virtualbox--I'm still having trouble figuring out if it's capable of running open-gl. I tried running matlab -nosoftwareopengl and got the two libGL errors again but not the last line. Again, the matlab logo screen opens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to link the libstdc++ library used by Matlab with the one installed in the system.

At the terminal type the following:

```
  sudo ln -sf /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.19 /usr/local/Matlab/R2015a/sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6
```

You may need to adjust the path to take into account where Matlab is installed in your system. This solved the problem for me.

Comment: This seems to have fixed the libGL errors. Thanks! But I'm still getting "MATLAB is selecting SOFTWARE OPENGL rendering" and the logo screen that doesn't open.

Comment: You can try to start Matlab using `matlab -nodesktop` from the terminal and then issue `opengl('save','hardware')` at the command prompt and then restart.

Comment: I get: MATLAB:settings:core:NoWritePermissionOnDirectory Internal Error: No write permission on directory /home/abigail/.matlab/R2015a/temp0x3150x97b. Details: fl:filesystem:AccessDenied.. when I run 'matlab -nodesktop.

Comment: Also afterwards when I enter opengl('save', 'hardware') I get: MATLAB:dispatcher:loadLibrary Can't reload '/usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libmwhgbuiltins.so'.
Caught MathWorks::System::FatalException

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with MATLAB not starting up and having only the blue logo display. When I tried running matlab from the terminal, I got the same `MATLAB is selecting SOFTWARE OPENGL rendering` error message.

Trying `matlab -nodesktop` started up, but gave me the same error message the OP described in the comments to Harris's answer.

To fix this, go to your home directory then into you `.matlab` folder and make sure that all subfolders and files in that directory are owned by your username, not by root.

To change ownership, use `sudo chown username:group folder` where username and group are default to your Ubuntu login username.

For example, in OP's case it would be:

```
sudo chown abigail:abigail /home/abigail/.matlab/R2015a
```

The same goes for any files and subfolders inside of the `R2015a` folder